# Is the average order of a product of arithmetic functions the product of the average orders?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, average, arithmetic-functions

If we have
$$\sum_{n \leq x} f(n) \sim \sum_{n \leq x} g(n)$$
$$\sum_{n \leq x} h(n) \sim \sum_{n \leq x} k(n)$$
does it follow that
$$\sum_{n \leq x} f(n)h(n) \sim \sum_{n \leq x} g(n)k(n)$$

In other words, if $g$ is an average order of $f$ and $k$ is an average order of $h$, then is $gk$ an average order of $fh$?

Comment: Number theory would have been much easier with this. Unluckily, it is blatantly false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example pick $f(n) = 1+(-1)^n, h(n) = 1-(-1)^n, g(n)=k(n)=1$

Comment: That makes sense.  I suppose this same idea works even when the functions don't have an average value, but what about if the functions are required to be multiplicative?

Comment: @Steven: you can devise as many counterexamples as you wish by considering multiplicative and oscillating functions, like any non-principal Dirichlet character. The average value of $\chi_4$ is zero, the average value of $\chi_4^2$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, for instance.